# dynamically populate mysql array into drop down menu

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database that I want to get data out onto a website. It contains states listed by name and id. Counties listed by id, namne , and state that contains thems ID and then clubs that exist , with a reference to the county id's that they exist in and columns for their actual data.

What I've got :

A drop down menu that populates itself with state id and name.

What I'd like to accomplish:

On selection of state , let's say ny , take it's id and use this in gathering another mysql array for the county drop down. I'd like it to dynamically occur on selection of state , maybe even giving a count of results next to the drop down.

```
$resstate = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM state ORDER by longstate;") or die("Note: " . mysql_error());
State:
   <select name="State" size=1>
     <?
        while( $rs = mysql_fetch_array( $resstate ) ) {
            echo "<option value=" .$rs['id'] . ">" . $rs['longstate'] . "</option>";
        }
   echo "</select>";
?>
```

I know I could use a JavaScript `onChange="this.form.submit()"` on the first drop down, but it's my understanding that I'd then be making a new page at that point and don't know if I could keep the functionality of the state drop down, say if you accidentally chose new Hampshire when you wanted New York.

here's an example of the current array filling the drop down :

http://snowmobileamerica.com/countytest.php

----EDIT---

Using Dagons Advice , I looked into Ajax.

I made a php file that's supposed to query the database based on a reference to getcounty.php?q=

The file is created as follows :

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$cn=mysql_connect("localhost","user","password") or die("Note: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("snowusa_clubs", $cn);

$sql="SELECT * FROM county WHERE state_id = '".$q."' ORDER by name";

$result = mysql_query($sql);


echo "<select name="County" size=1>";

while($rc = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<option value=" .$rc['id'] . ">" . $rc['name'] . "</option>";
 }

 echo "</select>";

mysql_close($cn);
 ?>
```

If i try to run it manually  http://www.snowmobileamerica.com/getcounty.php?q=33 I get a 500 internal server error...

Any ideas where I went wrong?

Comment: sounds like a job for AJAX

Comment: I know 0 about ajax, care to ellaborate ?

Comment: not really, i expect any of the millions of sites on the topic could provide you with better information than me. There is already enough needles duplication on the internet

Comment: thanks for the tip @Dagon
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp  I think I  can butcher this to do what I want.

Comment: never ever use 3wschools as a resource, its full of dangerously wrong information. http://w3fools.com

Comment: you don't need to write echo "Conn ok<br>"; echo " Database opened<br>"; because you already checking it using mysql_error

Comment: @DipeshParmar thanks, I also needed the ; at the end of the echo lines, but still no go.

Error log reads :

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' on line 17

Line 17 is the first echo statement, and it is closed by a ;

Comment: silly mistake, needed to escape \"County\"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not able to comment yet. 
but for the second question try:

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$cn=mysql_connect("localhost","user","password") or die("Note: " . mysql_error());
echo "Conn ok<br>";
mysql_select_db("snowusa_clubs", $cn);
echo " Database opened<br>"; 
$sql="SELECT * FROM county WHERE state_id = '$q' ORDER by name";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo " Database queried <br>";

echo "<select name='County' size=1>";

while($rc = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<option value='" .$rc['id'] . "'>" . $rc['name'] . "</option>";//added single quotes in the value
 }
echo "</select> ";

mysql_close($cn);
?>
```

Comment: I ended up escaping County as \"County\"  dunno if it makes a difference, either way you were right on track :)

Answer (score 1):

try adding an id to the element, then make an ajax call to a handler with jquery:

```
$("#State").change(function() {
$.post("path/to/request handler/" , { "State" : $(this).val() },
function(data){
    if (data == "OK"){
        //add some elements here
    } else {
        //handle an error here
    }
});
```

});

Comment: missed a semicolon after echo "<select name="County" size=1>"

Comment: just saw this... rather than 'county' , I used \"county\"

If you want to make it a new answer, I'll accept it :)